# XStream ProcessAnnotations

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am using `XStream` to convert an array in java to xml. I am adding this line to use annotations.

```
 XStream xStream = new XStream();
xStream.processAnnotations(CollectionConverter.class);
```

But it says `processAnnotations` is undefined for `xStream`. I have `xstream.jar` in the build path. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XStream` `processAnnotations` method has been introduced in `XStream` version 1.3, for older versions `Annotations.configureAliases(XStream xstream, Class<?>... topLevelClasses)` method can be used instead.

- [XStream class processAnnotations Documentation](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#processAnnotations-java.lang.Class:A-)
- [Annotations class Documentation](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/annotations/Annotations.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was having both XStream and Xstream 1.4 jar. When I removed the older jar and retained only XStream 1.4  jar, it is working fine.

Comment: Also, If I want to annotate only an array, without declaring a class to contain the array, is that possible?  When I am adding Xstream alias inside the method where the array is declared, I am getting an error that "XStreamAlias is disallowed for this location" Any workaround?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want then answer is no, that is not possible. XStream (and other serializing frameworks) can serialize only class members not local variables that are declared in methods. However, that is another question, and proper way would be to just ask new question and let people answer...

Comment: please use http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html (codehouse is no longer available)